# Калькуляция цены при выборе даты

Tags: php, javascript, html

Приветствую! Подскажите как имея 2 поля даты приезда и уезда можно реализовать калькуляцию суммы.
На данный момент с базы выгружается сумма за день, нужно в real-time при выборе дат чтобы производилась калькуляция. Т.е.

`<label for="dtarrive">Дата заезда</label>
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="dtarrive" name="dtarrive"/>
<label for="dtdepart">Дата выезда</label>
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="dtdepart" name="dtdepart"/>
<label for="price">Цена за 1 день</label>
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="price" name="price" value="{$val.price}" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="{$val.price}" disabled />`

```
<label for="price">Итоговая цена</label> ?????
```

Comment: где будет прописана сумма?

Comment: В <label for="price">Итоговая цена</label>
<input type="text" ..... disabled /> Дальше будет садится в базу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как можно убрать выбор даты которая прошла?

Если я правильно понял, то вам необходимо скрывать от пользователя поле выбора даты после того как он(пользователь) внес значение.

Если это не верно, то уточните вопрос и я перепишу ответ, а если верно,то здесь необходимо дополнить действие на событие изменения поле даты

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="dtarrive">Дата заезда
   <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dtarrive" name="dtarrive"/>
</label>
<label for="dtdepart">Дата выезда
   <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dtdepart" name="dtdepart"/>
</label>
<label for="price">Цена за 1 день</label>
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="price" name="price" value="10000" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="10000" disabled />

<label for="price">Итоговая цена</label><span id="cost"></span>
<script>
  var dtarrive=0, dtdepart=0, price=$('#price').val();
  $('#dtarrive,#dtdepart').change(function(){
    dtarrive=$('#dtarrive').val();
    dtdepart=$('#dtdepart').val();
    if(dtarrive) $('label[for="dtarrive"]').fadeOut();
    if(dtdepart) $('label[for="dtdepart"]').fadeOut();
    if(dtarrive && dtdepart ) {
        //для I-7 
        //dtarrive=new Date(dtarrive.replace(/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/, '$2/$3/$1'));
      dtarrive=new Date(dtarrive);
      dtdepart=new Date(dtdepart);
      var cost=Math.round((dtdepart-dtarrive)/1000/3600/24)*price;
      $('#cost').text(cost);
    }
  });
</script>
```

как вы видите здесь была изменена структура html для удобства обращения к скрываемым элементам и добавлено пару строк в скрипте

Comment: либо     if(dtarrive) $('#dtarrive').attr('disabled','disabled');
    if(dtdepart) $('#dtdepart').attr('disabled','disabled');

Comment: если вы хотите скрыть выбор не ценою сокрытия поля, а ценою сокрытия возможности выбора

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то дату приезда и дату отъезда вписывает пользователь, находясь на странице и как только он ввел обе даты, необходимо ему вывести итоговую сумму.

Если это не верно, то уточните вопрос и я перепишу ответ, а если верно,то здесь работа с датами

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="dtarrive">Дата заезда</label>
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="dtarrive" name="dtarrive"/>
<label for="dtdepart">Дата выезда</label>
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="dtdepart" name="dtdepart"/>
<label for="price">Цена за 1 день</label>
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="price" name="price" value="10000" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="10000" disabled />

<label for="price">Итоговая цена</label><span id="cost"></span>
<script>
  var dtarrive=0, dtdepart=0, price=$('#price').val();
  $('#dtarrive,#dtdepart').change(function(){
    dtarrive=$('#dtarrive').val();
    dtdepart=$('#dtdepart').val();
    if(dtarrive && dtdepart ) {
        //для I-7 
        //dtarrive=new Date(dtarrive.replace(/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/, '$2/$3/$1'));
      dtarrive=new Date(dtarrive);
      dtdepart=new Date(dtdepart);
      var cost=Math.round((dtdepart-dtarrive)/1000/3600/24)*price;
      $('#cost').text(cost);
    }
  });
</script>
```

как вы видите для наглядности я подставил стоимость дня 10000 и подключил библиотеку jquery для быстроты обращения к элементам, также добавил вывод в span

Comment: Идеально подробно и понятно! Благодарю, еще вопрос как можно убрать выбор даты которая прошла?